# git lfs pushed only the placeholder file

Tags: git, git-lfs

I tried to take an existing git-lfs repository I have and push it to a secondary remote. On the secondary remote, an LFS file seemed to get pushed as if git-lfs's 'placeholder' file (text file with three lines: version, oid, size) was the real file. Trying to clone the secondary remote also fails with: `Smudge error: Error downloading ... Object does not exist on the server`.

The secondary remote has other LFS files which are stored properly. The file in question is also stored properly on the repo's 'primary' remote, and in my local repository (meaning: I see the actual file, not the placeholder).

I'm not sure how/why this happened (git lfs was initialized in my local repo, the push hooks were installed as far as I can tell), but I'd like to push the actual file. How can I do this?

I've tried `git lfs push --all secondary-remote branch-name`, `git lfs push secondary-remote --object-id "abc123"`, but neither seemed to have any effect (they both print a "Uploading LFS objects: 100% ..." message, but the file still doesn't appear on the remote).

**edit:** A co-worker did a `git lfs pull` and a `git lfs push` and it seemed to fix things. I'm not quite sure why though, given that my local repo already had the actual binary file checked out.

Comment: The placeholder *is* the real file as far as Git itself is concerned. The secondary repository needs to have a "smudge" filter set up so that it knows that, once the real file that is a placeholder comes out of Git, the secondary repo should *replace* it in the work-tree with the fake file, which is the content from the LFS server of which Git itself is completely unaware. In other words, the secondary remote isn't set up to lie to Git correctly yet. I don't use Git-LFS so I'm not sure how to do the setting-up part.

Comment: @torek AFAIK `.gitattributes` is what sets up the filter, which is checked in and pushed to the secondary repository. Although I don't actually care so much about whether the remote (github in this case) displays the file correctly, just whether it can be checked out, which in this case it can't, with an error of ` Smudge error: Error downloading.... Object does not exist on the server`. So I don't think the smudge filter is the (only) problem.

Comment: I don't know how to make GitHub read the LFS-server file at all, but it will need more than just `.gitattributes` since that tells which filter to use but doesn't define the filter itself (the filter definition goes in a `.git/config` or `.gitconfig` file). Does the indirection file (the lie told to Git, as it were) provide the full URL or just a path on the LFS-server?

Comment: @torek My impression is that GitHub's repositories are pre-configured with the LFS hooks. There are already other LFS files pushed to this remote that work correctly.

I'm not sure what URL you're referring to -- the indirection files contain a version, hash, and size.

Comment: The version/hash/size tells some LFS server (not a Git server) what to retrieve. But what *server*? It's not the Git server. The server will be specified by a separate URL, e.g., http://host.name/top/path or some such.

Comment: Sure, but the LFS server endpoint isn't stored in the indirection file. I believe git lfs tracks it internally somehow. Locally, you can get the paths to the lfs endpoints per remote from `git lfs env`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167759/discussion-between-alec-and-torek).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when I downloaded LFS files to my repo before I installed git lfs there. After the installation, the files only contained the links.

As in the edit of the question, when I ran

```
git lfs pull
git lfs push
```

after [installing git lfs](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#installing-git-lfs) the files got updated.

(No idea if this is a full-fledged answer, but this was the only place I found addressing this problem. Maybe it is of help to more people.)

Answer (score 0):

What caused the same problem for me was a mixup in the local gitconfig file.

Specifically, the "lfs" section for the git server had the wrong address - it pointed to a temporary local "server" I created for testing.  So git lfs push the binaries into the local "server" and thought everything was ok while

I'm not sure what caused the mixup, possibly a bug in git lfs, or possibly something I did by mistake.

In my case the config file had these sections:

```
[lfs]
    access = basic
[lfs "file:///<SOME_LOCAL_PATH>"]
    access = basic
```

1. I deleted the first section with the "empty" lfs
2. I changed the url in the second section to be the real url of the server, plus the suffix.  In my case it's an Azure server, so I changed this to:

```
    [lfs "https://my.azureaddress.com/OrgName/_git/RepoName.git/info/lfs"]
        access = basic
```

3. I ran the following command to re-push things:

   git lfs push --all

Then I could see my files on the new server and git clone worked successfully.

You can also double check this by running

```
git lfs env
```

which will print a bunch of lines, notice the "Endpoint" lines, if they are different than what you expect then what I described above may help you.